# How to find a valid point if NavMeshObstacle is blocking path?

Tags: unity, navmesh

[image]

Is there any way to find the closest valid point to my target if a NavMeshObstacle is blocking my agent's path? This point can be any point along the red line in the image above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NavMesh.CalculatePath does return you a partial path if it cannot reach the destination. You can try reading the last corner of the path that you get returned.

Source: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMesh.CalculatePath.html